# Search Input only getting results from one page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a webpage where it has a table with some data but this page happens to have multiple pages. I tried to implement a search input but what happens it that it only gets the results from the page I am on and not every page. Can someone help me with this?

Here's the code from the search function:

```
const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');

searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', function(event){
    let searchQuery = 
    event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    // console.log(event.target.value)
    console.log(searchQuery);

    const TableRow = document.querySelectorAll('li.table-row');

    let allDataArray = [];

    TableRow.forEach(datapair => {
        let uni = datapair.querySelector('div.col.col-2');
        let course = datapair.querySelector('div.col.col-3');

        if (uni && course) {
            allDataArray.push(uni, course);
        }
    });
    console.log(allDataArray)
})
```

If needed here's the code from the pagination:

```
<div class="pagination">
   <nav>
      <ul class="pager">
         <?php
         $totalPages = (int) ceil($totalRows / $limit);
         $showPages = 7;

         if ($page > 1) {
           echo '<li class="pager__item pager__item--prev">
             <a class="pager__link" href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="12" viewbox="0 0 8 12">
                   <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                      <path fill="#33313C" d="M7.41 1.41L6 0 0 6l6 6 1.41-1.41L2.83 6z"></path>
                   </g>
                </svg>
              </a>
            </li>';
         }

         // Show the first two pages
         for ($i = 1; $i <= min(2, $totalPages); $i++) {
            $isActive = ($i === $page) ? 'active' : '';
            echo '<li class="pager__item"><a class="pager__link ' . $isActive . '" href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
         }

         if ($page > $showPages - 2) {
            echo '<li class="pager__item"><span class="pager__link">...</span></li>';
         }

         // Show the pages between the first and last two pages
         $halfMaxVisiblePages = (int) floor($showPages / 2);
         $start = (int) max(3, $page - $halfMaxVisiblePages);
         $end = (int) min($totalPages - 2, $start + $showPages - 1);

         for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++) {
           $isActive = ($i === $page) ? 'active' : '';
           echo '<li class="pager__item"><a class="pager__link ' . $isActive . '" href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
         }

         if ($page < $totalPages - $showPages + 3) {
            echo '<li class="pager__item"><span class="pager__link">...</span></li>';
         }

         // Show the last two pages
         for ($i = max($totalPages - 1, $showPages); $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
             $isActive = ($i === $page) ? 'active' : '';
             echo '<li class="pager__item"><a class="pager__link ' . $isActive . '" href="?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
         }

         if ($page < $totalPages) {
            echo '<li class="pager__item pager__item--next">
                 <a class="pager__link" href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="12" viewbox="0 0 8 12">
                       <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                           <path fill="#33313C" d="M7.41 1.41L6 0 0 6l6 6 1.41-1.41L2.83 6z"></path>
                       </g>
                    </svg>
                 </a>
               </li>';
         }
         ?>
      </ul>
   </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: The pages of the table come from your server, but the search function works only on the client, where it "sees" only one page of data. What you want to achieve requires a search request to the server.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen yeah ig that makes sense. I’ll try to achieve something like that